# MySQL - C# - System.FormatException Error

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I decided to create an application that connects to an MySQL server but it seems that there is a problem with my code.

```
public partial class FRM_LOGIN : Form
{
private MySqlConnection connection;
private string server;
private string database;
private string uid;
private string password;

public FRM_LOGIN()
{
        InitializeComponent();

}


private void BTN_CONNECT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        server = "localhost";
        database = "databasenamehere";
        uid = "root";
        password = "root";
        string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
                                  database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";old guids=true;";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
                if (TXTBOX_USERNAME.Text == "" || TXTBOX_PASSWORD.Text == "")
                {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all the fields of the login form.");
                }
                else
                        try
                        {
                                connection.Open();
                                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE (user_id=@id AND user_password=@pwd)", connection);
                                com.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("id", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = this.TXTBOX_USERNAME.Text;
                                com.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("pwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = this.TXTBOX_PASSWORD.Text;
                                MySqlDataReader myReader = com.ExecuteReader();
                                myReader.Read();
                                if (myReader.HasRows == true)
                                {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull", "Login Information");
                                        this.Hide();
                                        FRM_MAIN frm_main = new FRM_MAIN();
                                        frm_main.Show();
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name or Password", "Hello", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                        this.Close();
                                }
                                connection.Close();
                        }
                        catch (MySqlException ex)
                        {
                                throw;
                        }
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
                {
                case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator", " Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;

                case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
        }
}


}
```

ALOT of it is patch work from various answers from here and some tutorials, so  please don't judge, complete newbie here.

So as most of you can tell, i have a form with 2 textboxes and a button. My goal was to authenticate the user by using finding out if the credentials are in the table tbl_login. If there are results, close form1 open another form.

My problem at the moment is that every time I click the button an exception is thrown.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

and it points me out to the

```
MySqlDataReader myReader = com.ExecuteReader();
```

Any ideas why this keeps on happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see my comment about plaintext passwords: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823825/c-sharp-syntax-error-in-sql-update-statement#comment66937789_39823825

Comment: You have a lot of problems in your code, if we start with SqlInejction, plain text passwords, really bad structure of the code, you leave the connection open if exception happen, no polymorphism, you should build connection string in the web.config/app.config.

For your exception problem, from what I have seen, the password in connection string should be written as `PWD` not Password or combination UserID/Password. See article about MySql Connection String https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/.

Comment: See the doc page we wrote up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/12379/executing-sql-statements-as-a-command#t=201610040255177299807) and note **note2:** that I put at the bottom

Comment: Thank you guys. It just seems that every time I try to tackle this one all I find is either tutorials that are way too simple or way to advanced for me. I guess I will start over.